# How to prevent before and beforeEach in a file from applying to all tests in all files?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have automated my apis using mocha.
The structure is like-

1.For each api there is one **api_namex.js** file inside which the mocha test resides

2. each api_namex.js file has one **describe()** and multiple **it()** inside the **describe()**
3. Now if I use **beforeEach()** in one of the **api_namex.js** file(say api_name1.js) then also while running the entire test suite which involves running all api_namex.js files, **beforeEach() is getting called for all these files**.

**How should I make it run only for the intended api_namex.js file only?**
Same issue with before also.

**my_areas.js** file is attached below.I have used beforeEach() here.But while running the entire test suite this beforeEach is getting called before each and every test case.**I want it before each test cases inside this describe() only**.

```
var should = require('should'),
    supertest = require('supertest'),
    servicesGenerator = require('../../utils/services_generator_test.js'),
    responseMsg = require('../../utils/response_messages.js'),
    helper = require('../../utils/helper.js'),
    testData = require('../../utils/test_data.js'),
    apiEndPoints = require('../../utils/api_endpoints.js');

beforeEach(function (done) {
    clearMyAreas();
    done();
});

describe('My Areas', function () {

    it('1: All Data Valid', function (done) {
        servicesGenerator.postPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.myAreas)
            .send(getValidMyAreasBody())
            .end(function (err, res) {
                baseValidator(err, res, 1, responseMsg.myAreasSuccess);
                areasValidator(err, res, 1);
                done();
            });
    });

    it('2: Invalid userId', function (done) {
        servicesGenerator.postPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.myAreas)
            .send(getValidMyAreasBody(testData.userIdInvalid))
            .end(function (err, res) {
                baseValidator(err, res, 0, responseMsg.invalidUserId);
                done();
            });
    });
   });
```

Comment: If you want the beforeEach to be only for the `it`s in the describe, move the beforeEach into the describe too. Otherwise, you can nest describes, if you want the same `beforeEach` to run over several of them, then they're probably related enough that you could describe them as a group too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the docs you should be able to put `beforeEach` and `before` hooks inside your `describe` blocks and they should run in the context of that `describe`: https://mochajs.org/#hooks